# How do Wrapper, Bindings, Shims and Transpilers relate to each other

Tags: javascript, python, c++, wrapper, transpiler

I recently read [this question here in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8628326/what-is-the-difference-between-a-wrapper-bindings-and-a-port) and checked the links in the answer, but I am not sure I have fully understood it correctly.
Also, I would like to learn how these definitions compare to a concept which I think is related, namely transpilers. So I thought it was best to ask a new question instead of just commenting.

To summarize this is what I think I have understood:

- A transpiler is like using a program to do a port instead of having
  to do code it manually. Like a compiler but without having to go from a high level language to a lower one.
- A binding and a bridge are the same thing.
- A wrapper library can be a binding or not depending whether target
  and source are in the same language.
- The wrapper library's code is called a shim, if the wrapper is a
  binding the shim is called glue code.

This basic diagram I constructed while reading the definitions on Wikipedia and so on is what has helped me to articulate the bullet points above so I am adding it for reference.

[Wrappers Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gP7Nk.png)

Comment: "transpiler" means the same thing as "compiler" but implies the target is commonly written by hand. Your last bullet point seems to be missing some punctuation.

Comment: Right, sorry about that, it made the sentence confusing. However, I don't quite understand why the target of a transpiler is commonly written by hand.

Comment: What do you think the difference between a compiler and a transpiler is?

Comment: That the compiler's output is always something more "down to the metal" whereas in the transpiler we could go from C++ to Javascript for example. Is my assumption wrong?

Comment: That’s kind of it! A compiler is a program that converts one language to another. Everything people call a “transpiler” is also a compiler. The word “transpiler” just implies that the target language is high-level. That’s all I meant by the first comment.