# What happens to performance when calling C code from dart Flutter desktop

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-desktop

Can I use dart:ffi to call C APIs on flutter desktop.
What happens to the performance after that ?
Can we use C to speed up flutter?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "what happens to performance after that"? Why do you expect using FFI to change future performance?

Comment: @smorgan not exactly. But sometimes calling code from another language introduces a bottleneck at least according to what I read here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8628326/what-is-the-difference-between-a-wrapper-a-binding-and-a-port) But like in the python community whenever  there is desperate for a speed up it gets written in C. I just want to know if you could do something like that.

Comment: Dart code in a Flutter app is compiled to native code; AFAIK there's no native compilation for Python. Whether C is faster than Dart compiled to native code for your specific use case, who knows. You'd have to profile and see.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I use dart:ffi to call C APIs on flutter desktop.

Yes. FFI works on all desktop platforms. It's used to implement some of the desktop implementations of some of the flutter.dev plugins, in fact.